# How many degrees of freedom does a spring pendulum have?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, degrees-of-freedom

I've been looking at a spring pendulum system, but I'm not sure how many degrees of freedom it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by a spring pendulum you are talking about a pendulum in which a massless spring connects the weight to the pivot, there are 3 degrees of freedom. Three quantities (along with associated conjugate momenta) that define the state of this system are two angles to determine the orientation of the spring (which could be azimuth and elevation angles), and the length of the spring. Another three quantities are the three Cartesian coordinates of the weight.

If you constrain the weight to move in two dimensions only, then you only need one angle and there are 2 degrees of freedom.